# Formula for point on regular polygon outline given angle and radius

Tags: math

I'm looking for a formula to compute points on the outline of a regular polygon (e.g. an octagon) given an angle and a radius. I can compute the vertices of the polygon using trigonomety and obtain the point on the outline using line/line intersection but this feels kind of clumsy. Is there a simple formula which gives the same result?

Comment: Sounds like a question for this site: https://math.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Your requirements are not clear. Just what "angle" are you given? Are you also given the number of sides of the polygon and its orientation?

Comment: You want the polar coordinates of a regular polygon. Is this correct?

Answer (score 1):

First of all, I assume that the polygon is oriented such that the first flat side is vertical on its right. The angle is measured with respect to the x-axis and we want to find the intersection of the ray and the polygon like this:

[image: Polygon]

We are given the polygon as number of sides and its [apothem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apothem). If you have the circumcircle, the Wikipedia page contains a formula for deriving the apothem. If your polygon is rotated, simply add or subtract the rotation angle from the query angle.

The first step involves finding the side that our ray intersects. Since the polygon is regular, this can simply be done by dividing and rounding. I call the corresponding angle of the side the *side angle*. The right side of the above pentagon has side angle 0, the next one has 72° and so on.

```
sectorAngle = 2 * PI / sides
sideAngle = sectorAngle * round(angle / sectorAngle)
```

Given this side angle, we can calculate the residual angle of our query ray and the perpendicular bisector of the side:

[image: Difference Angle]

```
diffAngle = angle - sideAngle
```

Note that this angle is signed.

Now we simply need to reconstruct the point in this rotated coordinate system, where the bisector is one axis and the perpendicular direction is the other. We need to walk a distance equal to the apothem along the bisector. The distance we need to walk perpendicularly is:

```
sideward = apothem * tan(diffAngle)
```

And we can use this to get our point:

```
sideNormalX = cos(sideAngle)
sideNormalY = sin(sideAngle)

pointX = centerX + sideNormalX * apothem - sideNormalY * sideward
pointY = centerY + sideNormalY * apothem + sideNormalX * sideward
```

Here is a JavaScript implementation:

```js
window.onload = function()  {
 canvas = document.getElementById('cnv');
 ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');   
 
 var pts = 100;
 for(var i = 0; i < pts; ++i) {
  plotPolygonPoint(i * 2 * Math.PI / pts, 5, 150, ctx);
 }
}

function plotPolygonPoint(angle, sides, apothem, ctx) {
 var sectorAngle = 2 * Math.PI / sides;
 var sideAngle = sectorAngle * Math.round(angle / sectorAngle); 
 
 var diffAngle = angle - sideAngle;
 
 var forward = apothem;
 var sideward = apothem * Math.tan(diffAngle);
 
 var sideNormalX = Math.cos(sideAngle);
 var sideNormalY = Math.sin(sideAngle);
 
 ctx.beginPath();
 ctx.ellipse(250 + sideNormalX * forward - sideNormalY * sideward, 250 + sideNormalY * forward + sideNormalX * sideward, 3, 3, 0, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
 ctx.fill();
}
```

```html
<canvas id="cnv" width="500" height="500" style="background-color:#ddd;"></canvas>
```

Answer (score 0):

The polar coordinates of a straight line going through two points `(x_1,y_1)` and `(x_2,y_2)` is

```
radius = (x_2*y_1 - x_1*y_2)/( (x_2-x_1)*cos(angle) - (y_2-y_1)*sin(angle) )
```

where the `angle` sweeps from `atan(y_1/x_1)` to `atan(y_2/x_2)`.

So all you have to do is divide a circle into `n` segments and find the `(x,y)` coordinates of each vertex. Then fit lines between two consecutive vertices with the formula above.

Below is an example of using this technique

[image: scr]